# Looking for E2E encrypted voice chat without sockets

Tags: chat, encryption, voip, skype

I am working for a big corporation from a remote location. The default for voice chat is Skype, which works most of the time alright. Unfortunately because of the VPNs, Firewalls and other networking layers we have to fight through, the voice chat functionality is not working most of the time. So we are looking for an alternative.

We have some requirements:

- It has to be E2E encrypted because the stuff we discuss is classified
- Preferably it uses only default ports like 80/443

I've tried Telegram which was working for text messages bus wasn't connecting when we tried an voice chat.

Comment: i don't think you understand what a socket is

Comment: @AnonymousLurker : Yeah, it's different then I thought it was. I've updatet the question, thanks!

Comment: Word of warning: fighting your employer's IT department and trying to circumvent their restrictions -- however onerous and misguided they may or may not be -- may not end well for you. This seems like a good topic to bring up with your manager and IT -- couch it in business terms and try to quantify the damage that non-functioning voice chat does to the company's bottom line. If you do decide to go the E2E voice chat route, however, I'd urge you to investigate the company's Network Use policy and be sure that your actions won't constitute a violation that could get you terminated.

Comment: @tonysdg, thank you for your concern. I'm a hired consultant, so if they let me go, I'll still have a job ;) 
Unfortunately the company has over 20k employees so it'll be hard to change their policies about the network restrictions. If the converstations are E2E encrypted it'll be fine in the eyes of the company... I hope

Comment: `because the stuff we discuss is classified` this alone rules out Skype. Skype, specially after the Microsoft takeover, spies on everything you do there, and there is a chance your chats and voice calls are already recorded and sold by them to who-knows-who. Read their privacy policy for some horrifing facts.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Open Whisper Systems' [Signal](https://signal.org/).
However, does "Voice chat" mean "multi-party calls" a.k.a. conference calls? I am not sure if Signal does multi-party calls; it might. But as for end-to-end encryption, I'd describe it as the gold standard.

A little bit of information about port numbers for Signal: 
 https://support.signal.org/hc/en-us/articles/360007320291-Firewall-and-Internet-settings

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use [webcall.me](https://webcall.me/)

The calls are secure, encrypted and peer to peer

It is free app but if you want to make calls even more secure you can buy webcall.me signalling server